# Add a video reply as an answer

Tags: discussion

I think it would be great, if people could demonstrate their solutions by submitting video snippets on how they solve questions, rather than paste some code. Video with an explanation would be an amazing feature.
What do you think?

Comment: Spammers' dream functionality;(

Answer (score 28):

Videos are not searchable. This is a *major* problem for a Q&A site.

I also struggle to see how a video answer would be useful. In the majority of cases, I would just be sitting there *listening* to you explain the problem, rather than *reading* an explanation. How does that help anyone? This isn't a Cooking site, where watching you go through the motions might be beneficial. I already know how to slouch at my computer and poke buttons on the keyboard. It is your thought process and understanding that I am interested in when I am reading answers, and neither of those things are compellingly conveyed in a video.

Worse, how are you going to share code snippets in a video? The only thing worse than an *image* of code is a *video frame* of code.

Comment: Spam, spam,  spam,  spam, spam, wonderful spam.  :(

Comment: It also takes the possbilities for annoying and disgusting spam to a whole new level and makes such _severely_ harder to detect by automated means (e.g SmokeDetector)

Comment: There are people with a particular learning style where they have trouble poring through words and words, that videos could be helpful for. I thought Google had some way to transcribe videos and make the text searchable.

Answer (score -16):

I think video not allow in stackowerflow community. but you can use gif.I'm using this software. for explain my problem. it useful so useful to me. explain to community,client,users etc. I thing it great.
[screen to gif](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/)

Comment: yup, that's cool, but i don't think StackOverflow allows inline gif?

Comment: it allow in StackOverflow. I already had used it. see below. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722810/browser-redirecting-chrome-and-firefox

Comment: ohh that's cool indeed. But what if you want to record audio and not share it video streaming service (ie, YouTube, Vimeo) ? I still think StackOverflow should have this option. Even if it's capped to some degree of length at first.

Comment: please visit @Wizzra and please see my updated answer. 
http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Wizzra, Not that I'd recommend it, but you can link to a video. (As always, you need to make sure your answer is still valid even without the link.) Oh, and while you're here, _do_ check out my profile for a demo of how annoyingly useless animated things can be :-)